# Destroy typeahead after the menu has been closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, typeahead, typeahead.js

I have a searchbox on which I initialize typeahead when I click on it, to some data from the server. Depending on the current page, I need to show/hide a footer in the search dropdown.

I went for the approach to destroy the typeahead and then recreate it, according to my needs. In this way, I also refresh the data from server, in case there's something changed.

For destroy I use this `this.$("#searchQuery").typeahead('destroy');` right at the top of the function that needs to initialize the typeahead, but the problem is that the menu is not destroyed. If I look at the dom, there are 4-5 or even more typeahead menu created.

So my question is, how can I properly 'reinitialize' a typeahead menu?

I forgot to mention I am using `twitter typeahead`

Comment: What is the jquery plugin that you are using?

Comment: You don't need to reference jQuery via `Window` using `this.$(...)`  you can just do `$("#searchQuery").typeahead("destroy");` and that could cause you problems depending on the function that you said you are using, which that line is in... because `this` may no longer represent the `Window` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to reference `jQuery` via `this` like you showed here

```
this.$("#searchQuery")
```

You should just do

```
$("#searchQuery").typeahead("destroy");
```

Without seeing more of an example I would say your problem might be because `this` inside your function is being bound to a different object than the one you were expecting.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Your line is inside your function so you can not guarantee that `this` will be `Window` and you have no need to use it in this case.

If this is not the problem then please provide a full html and javascript example, preferably on JsFiddle.